# Installing Windows 10 alongside Arch Linux

Tags: windows, arch-linux, dualboot

I have Arch installed on a Dell laptop (on a separate internal HDD - that holds upto 1TB), and it is running completely fine. I recently removed the Windows 11 installed on my Daichi nvme, and there were no problems whatsoever.

Now, on that particular nvme, I was trying to install Windows 10 from Microsoft's official repository of Non-activated ISOs, by using Etcher and `dd` to flash the ISO to the nvme. After booting into the nvme, I get the error message 'Missing media drivers ...'

Windows seems to hint at the fact that some drivers are ... *missing* from the ISO? That seems very unlikely.
Now I'm somewhat regretting the deletion.

Comment: Your not actually missing drivers you have a UEFI/Legacy Mode and GPT/MBR mismatch more than likely

Comment: Probably better to install Arch Linux as a VM inside the Windows host machine.

Comment: @Ramhound so is there any solution to this? Or will I have to give up hope for any Windows installation?

Comment: Why _are_ you flashing the ISO image directly to your NVMe disk? It's not exactly made for that usage.

Comment: As I noted, install Windows and then make Linux a VM.  Reasonably decent way of blending incompatible systems.

Comment: @u1686_grawity that is because at the moment I do not have a spare USB that can hold the 5.5GB Windows ISO. Is there a possible downside to doing what I'm doing?

Comment: @John I could do that, but I'm not able to install Windows right now (as I said in the question). My primary OS is arch linux for the moment, and it is working just fine

Comment: @DoofyDimwit: I suspect that yes, its "live" OS has been prepared to boot from a USB storage device and although the _install_ image bundled within includes NVMe drivers, the "live" OS possibly doesn't.

Comment: In that case, why not make _Windows_ a VM on Arch?

Comment: @DoofyDimwit There's no reason for [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting) to be used, as it's sole purpose was to support distros circa <2017 that lacked EFI boot - Arch supports EFI boot and Windows has supported it since Win7. I don't use Arch, but normally you'd re-configure the distro to use EFI boot by changing the disk to GPT, creating the EFI partition with the correct EFI boot GUID, then setting up the partition with the appropriate EFI boot files.

Comment: Alternatively, do you have _any_ spare USB regardless of capacity? There are other ways to install Windows without putting the entire image on the USB stick.

Comment: @u1686_grawity because a key reason for installation of Windows is running Visual Studio, and possibly some games. I tried running a W10 VM using VirtualBox, but in simple words my hardware cannot handle it - certainly not running games.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes, I do have a 2gig spare USB as of now.

Comment: @DoofyDimwit For the NVME drive, the only way it might work to boot WinPE _(the install ISO)_ is to pre-format the NVME drive in Arch _after converting Arch's OS drive to GPT_, configuring EFI boot, and disabling CSM Mode in the motherboard's UEFI firmware. You'll then want to configure the NVME drive with a GPT partition table, creating 5 partitions _(100MB EFI (FAT32), 128MB MSR (don't format), 6GB ISO (FAT32), OS (NTFS), 665MB WinRE (NTFS), all with the correct GUIDs)_ before writing the ISO to the ISO partition, then manually select the ISO partition from the UEFI boot options _cont'd..._

Answer (score 1):

> flash the ISO to the nvme

Although I'm not entirely sure, I *suspect* that the minimal "setup" OS that boots from the ISO image doesn't contain "boot" drivers for any other storage devices except USB and CD.

When you boot the ISO image, you aren't booting the *same* Windows as would be installed – you're booting a specially prepared mini-OS; still Windows 11 under the hood, but very stripped down. The actual OS to be installed is contained in the "Install.wim" image file within the ISO (and is unpacked during setup).

<del>So while the Install.wim certainly comes with standard NVMe drivers, I highly suspect that the "Setup" mini-OS *does not* – after all, it wasn't designed to be booted directly from NVMe.</del>

(Edit: On second thought, it definitely comes with NVMe drivers as it has to install the OS on NVMe... but the drivers are probably not configured to start *on boot*, as Windows makes that distinction.)

> at the moment I do not have a spare USB that can hold the 5.5GB

The ISO image consists of this "live" Windows PE OS (~700 MB) and an `Install.wim` image of a fresh Windows system (~5.0 GB), and according to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe--use-a-single-usb-key-for-winpe-and-a-wim-file---wim?view=windows-11), **those can be on separate drives.**

So you could *manually* prepare a bootable Windows installation USB (not using Rufus/Etcher but by unpacking the ISO yourself) *without* Install.wim included – the rest will fit within the 2GB USB stick that you have.

1. Start with regular a FAT32-formatted USB stick with one large partition.
2. Extract the files from the ISO image using `7z x` or `bsdtar -xf Win11.iso` in /home.
3. Copy all files except Install.wim onto the USB stick. (Do not create subfolders – keep 'sources', 'efi', 'autorun.inf', etc. directly at the root of the USB stick.)
4. Use GParted to create a temporary NTFS partition on your Arch disk, then copy the Install.wim image there.

According to MS docs, the installer will look for Install.wim on all FAT/exFAT/NTFS partitions.

If the installer can't find it automatically, it's still possible to manually install Windows by using `dism.exe` to extract Install.wim and `bcdboot` to set up the bootloader – a lot like installing Arch.

Comment: "_Although I'm not entirely sure, I suspect that the minimal "setup" OS that boots from the ISO image doesn't contain drivers for any other storage devices except USB and CD._" AFAIK, the current WinPE WIMs contains drivers necessary to detect NVME drives, but if not, the driver can be injected into the WinPE WIM with `dism` _(albeit this requires a Windows system to boot to - it might be possible to inject into the WinPE WIM while booted to the same WIM, but I've never tried it)_. Sometimes the hiccup occurs with UEFI firmware lacking NVME drivers and needing to be updated.

Comment: "_So you could manually prepare a bootable Windows installation USB (not using Rufus/Etcher but by unpacking the ISO yourself) without Install.wim included_" You can't unpack a WinPE ISO like that, as it won't boot - it has to be written as is to a partition, then the `install.wim` can be moved to another partition _(an [`unattend.xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/update-windows-settings-and-scripts-create-your-own-answer-file-sxs) answer file may still be required to point to the physical hardware location of the WIM)_

Comment: @JW0914: That might have been true for older versions but is no longer true for Win10/11, as far as I know – UEFI systems will just pick up `\efi\boot\bootmgfw.efi` that was unpacked as part of the ISO image. I've tried. Even for BIOS systems, you'll at most need to install the standard Windows bootsector with bootsect.exe (or ms-sys on Linux).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for letting me know =]

Comment: @u1686_grawity as soon as I boot into the stick, it warns me about not being able to find `install.wim` without giving me an option to browse for it, and pressing 'OK' just aborts the installation. I did not expect free ISOs from Microsoft to work. :|

Comment: @DoofyDimwit: I suppose that means it'll only look for Install.wim on CD and USB devices then. In that case, do the installation manually – open the Shift-F10 terminal, partition and format as per Microsoft's docs, unpack install.wim with DISM and install a bootloader.

Comment: @u1686_grawity when I do boot into the usb stick, diskpart does not show any other connected disks except the usb itself. Same thing with the NVME. How do I partition then? I cannot locate Install.wim because of this too.

Comment: Hmm, is your system firmware set to "RAID mode" or something? I remember that requires the special Intel RST drivers and won't work with standard NVMe drivers – if that's the case, it would also explain why the ISO wasn't able to boot directly as well.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Under the "SATA/NVMEe operation" section in the BIOS it does appear that "RAID On" is selected

Comment: @u1686_grawity sorry to bother you, and thank you so much for your help so far. I changed it to AHCI from the BIOS, and partitioned the NVMe. I don't think I can access the wim file from my HDD? As you said earlier I stored it on an NTFS partition

Comment: Does the HDD show up on DISKPART now? Does it have a drive letter?

Comment: Yes I can see all the drives. Thats how I partitioned the NVMe. It just says disk 0, 1 and so on.